# Decoupling package from dependency injection

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Currently having some issues in typescript with dependency injection.

I am trying to have a separate package that holds the typeorm services without coupling it to the dependency injection framework used in the main package.

However i cannot make this a smooth solution, i feel like i will end up with something that becomes maintenance and too highly custom.
Not to mention, what if the DI token for the service dependencies changes depending on framework used.

Solution 1: Custom class decorator in the package that assembles all service types into a list. Then run through in main package to add them to the framework.

Solution 2: Just an array with types added manually. Then run through in main package to add them to the framework.

Solution 3: Add every dependency injection framework to the service package (Multiple decorators that it supports)

Solution 4: Long list manuallly added to in the main framework referencing services in secondary package.

Is there anything that is easier?

Comment: If i understand you right, you can use peerDependencies feature of npm's packages, for optional installing dependencies in case when several package can be linked to one package without installing duplicated packages.